# JavaScript for getting value from html select and link to button

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var gch;
document.addEventListener('DOMcontentLoaded', Function()) {
  gch = document.getElementById('choose');

  if (localStorage['choose']) {
    gch = input;
  }
  input.onchange = function() {
    gch = this.value;
  }
}

function Visit() {
  if (gch == 1) {
    window.location = "index.html";
  } else if (gch == 2) {
    window.location = "input.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id='choose' aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Choose an Action:</option>
  <option value="1">ADD Patient</option>
  <option value="2">Delete Patient</option>
</select>

<button onclick="Visit()">go</button>
```

I wanted to create a drop-down menu with “Add Patient Name” and “Delete Patient Name" as options and a “Go!” button to go to the corresponding page from the home.
I was really new to js, kind of still using java logic to write js, cant figure out whats wrong

Comment: `gch = input` doesn't make any sense. Did you mean `gch = input.value`? Why are you only doing that when `localStorage['choose']` exists?

Comment: You have an extra `)` in `Function())`. The second `)` should be after the function body. Also `Function` should be `function`, as JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a bunch of syntax errors and typos.

`DOMcontentLoaded` should have an uppercase `C`.

`Function` should have a lowercase `f`.

The closing parenthesis in the `addEventListener` call should be after the function body.

You assigned `gch` to the `<select>` element, when it should be `input`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `localStorage`, and `localStorage` can't be used in Stack Snippets because of its sandboxing, so I left that out. I suspect what you want is `gch = localStorage.getItem("choose");`

```js
var gch;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('choose');

  input.onchange = function() {
    gch = this.value;
  }
})

function Visit() {
  if (gch == 1) {
    window.location = "index.html";
  } else if (gch == 2) {
    window.location = "input.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id='choose' aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Choose an Action:</option>
  <option value="1">ADD Patient</option>
  <option value="2">Delete Patient</option>
</select>

<button onclick="Visit()">go</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm just really new to js inside of HTML, this really helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that...

```js
document
.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () =>
  {
  const 
    inChoose = document.getElementById('choose')
  , gch =
    { add : 'index.html' 
    , del : 'input.html'
    }
  document
  .getElementById('bt-go')
  .onclick = () =>
    {
    if (gch[inChoose.value])
      window.location = gch[inChoose.value]
    }
  })
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id='choose' aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Choose an Action:</option>
  <option value="add">ADD Patient</option>
  <option value="del">Delete Patient</option>
</select>

<button id="bt-go">go</button>
```

Comment: Ugh, those commas and unnecessary line-breaks! Did you get that awful habit from SQL?

Answer (score 0):

There was some error and syntax error in document.addEventListener and function inside document.addEventListener.

Try this:

```js
let gch;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const input = document.getElementById('choose');
    input.onchange = function () {
        gch = this.value;
    }
})
function Visit() {
    if (gch == 1) {
        console.log("Uncomment below line to redirect to index.html");
        // window.location = "index.html";
    } else if (gch == 2) {
        console.log("Uncomment below line to redirect to input.html");
        // window.location = "input.html";
    }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id='choose' aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>Choose an Action:</option>
    <option value="1">ADD Patient</option>
    <option value="2">Delete Patient</option>
</select>
<button onclick="Visit()">go</button>
```